# Outputting correct prime numbers in Java

Tags: java, primes

I have a small issue with a Java program I am doing at the moment:

```
public class PrimeNumbers {

    public static void computePrimeNumbers(boolean[] prime, int n) {
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (prime[i] == true) {
                for (int j = 2; j < n; j++) {
                    if ((j%i == 0) && (j != i)) {
                        prime[j] = false;
                        //System.out.println(j + " = " + prime[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n = 13;
        boolean[] prime = new boolean[n];

        prime[0] = false;
        prime[1] = false;

        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            prime[i] = true;
        }

        computePrimeNumbers(prime, n);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " = " + prime[i]);   
        }
    }
}
```

The program should output "true" if the integer (i) is a prime, and false if otherwise. The commented out piece of code in the if-statement within the nested for loop gives me the correct boolean statements (i.e. it shows the integers which aren't prime numbers when running it), however the last for loop within main seems to just show the initial values given to the prime array - so I assume the results from the computePrimeNumbers are being overwritten somehow, somewhere.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Did you try walking through the logic on paper? using old-school pen & pad ?

Comment: `if (prime[i] = true)` Are you comparing for equality, or assigning?

Comment: It often helps to simply make sure you're assumptions about logic are true

Comment: ah a classic, sneaky assignment

Comment: Ah, yes I forgot the extra = in the if (prime[i] == true) statement in the method. Nevermind then, the output is correct now

Comment: @S.R. we dont need ==.  just if(prime[i]) should suffice... ?

Comment: @wrongAnswer Yes, that would suffice actually, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `if` condition uses the assignment operator instead of the equality operator:

```
if (prime[i] = true) {  // should be if(prime[i] == true) or just if(prime[i])
```

`prime[i] = true` will assign the value `true` to the array element and the `if` condition will always evaluate true.

Comment: Are you sure we need even == should just if(prime[i]) suffice... ?

Comment: @wrongAnswer Sure. But the point was to point out the difference between the two operators.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (prime[i] == true) {

    for (int j = 2; j < n; j++) {
        if ((j % i == 0) && (j != i)) {
            prime[j] = false;
             System.out.println(j + " = " + prime[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
4 = false
6 = false
8 = false
10 = false
12 = false
6 = false
9 = false
12 = false
10 = false
0 = false
1 = false
2 = true
3 = true
4 = false
5 = true
6 = false
7 = true
8 = false
9 = false
10 = false
11 = true
12 = false
```